# How do I just display the value for the variations in woocommerce email?

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

How do I just display the value for the variations in woocommerce email? Right now it's displaying the label and value. It's display like this -> Size: M
But I want to display only the value "M" Also, how do I remove the  ":" ?

```
        <td class="td" style="text-align: right; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Courier New', 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace;">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $item_meta->meta ) ) {
                echo nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true, '_', "\n" ) );
            } ?>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woocommerce uses a class called *WC_Order_Item_Meta* to display order item meta. It is used by Woocommerce *email-order-items.php* template.

Add a `woocommerce_order_items_meta_display`filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_items_meta_display'
```

Inject two dependencies `$output` and `$obj`:

`function ($output, $obj) {...}, 10, 2);`

Check if order item is of *variable* type:

```
if ($obj->product->parent->product_type == 'variable'){
```

Scrub the output:

```
ltrim(explode(':', $output)[1])
```

In conclusion, this is what the code looks like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_items_meta_display', function ($output, $obj) {
if($obj->product->parent->product_type == 'variable') {
    $output = ltrim(explode(':', $output)[1]);
}
return $output; },10,2);
```

Comment: I have to wonder how the OP's clients are supposed to know what the variation info stands for without the labels, but this is a thorough answer! +1

Comment: Yes @helgatheviking Half the time I wonder, why am I writing answers for these perverted questions. But in the end I learn something too.

Comment: So much to be learned in answering questions. That must be why we're here (oh and hard-core procrastination!). I do like to make people clarify why they are doing something. Often, it is because they've got tunnel vision and there's actually a much better approach once I know what the end goal is.

Comment: I will have a thead for description what they are. For example, price, size,quantity. That's why I want to remove the label since i have then in thead.

Comment: This only works for me if the product only have one attribute. any thoughts?